# How do function pointers work?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, function-pointers

I'm asking some specific questions.

1. How can I initialize them in a class?
2. How can I pass a function as an argument?
3. Do function pointers need to be declared and defined in the class?

For question number 2 here is what I mean:

```
void s(void) {
   //...
}

void f(function) { // what should I put as type to pass a function as an argument
   //...
}

f(s);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To define a function pointer, use the following syntax:

```
return_type (*ref_name) (type args, ...)
```

So, to define a function reference named "doSomething", which returns an `int` and takes in an `int` argument, you'd write this:

```
int (*doSomething)(int number);
```

You can then assign the reference to an actual function like this:

```
int someFunction(int argument) {
   printf("%i", argument);
}

doSomething = &someFunction;
```

Once that's done, you can then invoke it directly:

```
doSomething(5); //prints 5
```

Because function pointers are essentially just pointers, you can indeed use them as instance variables in your classes.

When accepting function pointers as arguments, I prefer to use a `typedef` instead of using the cluttered syntax in the function prototype:

```
typedef int (*FunctionAcceptingAndReturningInt)(int argument);
```

You can then use this newly defined type as the type of the argument for the function:

```
void invokeFunction(int func_argument, FunctionAcceptingAndReturningInt func) {
   int result = func(func_argument);
   printf("%i", result);
}

int timesFive(int arg) {
   return arg * 5;
}
invokeFunction(10, &timesFive); //prints 50
```

Comment: You do not need & to obtain the address of a function.

Comment: @Luis G. Costantini R.: You do need the `&` for pointers-to-members (ISO 14882:2003 C++ Standard 5.3.1/3). I personally use `&` in all cases to indicate that I'm actually passing a function pointer.

Comment: @Jacob Relkin - I've known well from University that you use this very rarely?. When would one resort to using function pointers?

Comment: @sil3nt: in standard library algorithms

Comment: @sil3nt: Function pointers are the way to have callback functions **in a C-compatible public API**.  Within a C++ module, however, a pointer to an abstract class with an appropriate virtual function is much more flexible.

Comment: @sil3nt: In C, one can use function pointers to simulate what you do with virtual functions in C++.  That is, your "objects" can be structs or arrays with a set of pointers to functions, and then different "classes" can put their own "method" pointers into those slots.  Another use is for event-driven "callback" types of designs.

Answer (score 2):

it is not the **strict** answer , but to include configurable/assignable code as a class member, I would mention using a class/struct with the operator() . For example:

```
struct mycode
{
    int k;

    mycode(int k_) : k(k_)
    {
    }

    int operator()(int x)
    {
     return x*k;
    }
};


class Foo
{
public : Foo(int k) : f(k) {}
public : mycode f;
};
```

You can do:

```
Foo code(5);
std::cout << code.f(2) << std::endl;
```

it will print '10' , it I wrote everything ok.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare `f` in this way:

```
void f(void (*x)())
{
  x();  // call the function that you pass as parameter (Ex. s()).
}
```

[here](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html) is an excellent tutorial about function pointers and callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

To answer 3rd question, you do not have to declare it in a class. But not to transgress encapsulation, I usually prefer member function pointers or functors which pointees are again members of classes. Examples above are C style function pointers except Luis G. Costantini R. You can take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx) for member function pointers approach. C style function pointers are generally considered, for example, callback mechanisms where there is a C code which you receive asynchronous messages. In such cases, there are no options rather than declaring handler methods in global scope.