# How do you pass a function as a parameter?

Tags: c++, function, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do function pointers work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528808/how-do-function-pointers-work)

How do you pass a function as a parameter?

Also can you pass a function from another class as a parameter (using objects?)?

Comment: The same way you pass anything else as a parameter. You put its name inside parentheses after the name of the function you wish to pass it to. Which part are you having trouble with? Hmm — perhaps the title didn't really say it all?

Answer (score 3):

Besides function pointers, you can use [std::function and std::bind](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#std-function) (or `boost` equivalents if you don't have C++11). These provide polimorphic function wrappers, so you can do stuff like defining this function, which takes an `std::function` that takes two ints and returns a double:

```
double foo(std::function<double(int, int)> f) {
  return 100*f(5,89);
}
```

then you can pass it anything that matches that signature, for example:

```
struct Adder {
  double bar(double a, double b) { return a+b;}
};

int main() {
  using namespace std::placeholders;
  Adder addObj;
  auto fun = std::bind(&AdderC::bar, &addObj, _1, _2); // auto is std::function<double(int,int)>

  std::cout << foo(fun) << "\n"; // gets 100*addObj.bar(5,89)
}
```

These are both easy to use an powerful, don't be mislead by the useless example. You can wrap plain functions, static functions, member functions, static member functions, functors...

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways.

One is the function pointer @dusktreader outlines.

The other is to use [functors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B), or function objects, where you define a class that overloads `operator()` with the parameters of the function, and then pass around an instance of the class.

I've always found the latter more intuitive, but either will do.

Comment: Functors only work when passed to a template function.

Comment: @MarkRansom function objects may also use a common base and dynamic dispatch via a `virtual`.

Comment: @MarkRansom not when they are `std::functions`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function pointer.  The syntax isn't too hard, and there's a wonderful page [here](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html)  that provides a thorough breakdown of how to use function pointers in c and c++.

From that page (http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html):

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 2.6 How to Pass a Function Pointer

// <pt2Func> is a pointer to a function which returns an int and takes a float and two char
void PassPtr(int (*pt2Func)(float, char, char))
{
   int result = (*pt2Func)(12, 'a', 'b');     // call using function pointer
   cout << result << endl;
}

// execute example code - 'DoIt' is a suitable function like defined above in 2.1-4
void Pass_A_Function_Pointer()
{
   cout << endl << "Executing 'Pass_A_Function_Pointer'" << endl;
   PassPtr(&DoIt);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this when i get home